# Why Google Material Icons Can't be Shown on Mobile

Tags: css, svg, material-design, text-rendering, materialize

I am using Materializecss and it uses Google design icons.
On some mobiles, [Google Material-Icons](http://www.google.com/design/icons/) can'be shown. What is caused it?

[image]

Comment: There are also references on the Material Design site about base versions for the Android operating system to support Material Design properly. You might have to cross reference that. See https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problems is occurred because of `text-rendering` property. Text-rendering is not a CSS standart but it allows use to choose text quality.

In google material css this property comes with it's default value . If you add this style you will solve the problem :

```
.material-icons {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

By this definition, we say to the browser that, "emphasize legibility  over rendering speed and geometric precision."

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-rendering/